# How to log/debug a Crossbar guest worker?

Tags: autobahn, crossbar

How can I capture output/logs from a guest worker and/or debug it? The worker is a regular Python3 Autobahn WAMP component. Whatever I `print` or `raise` or write to `stderr` is nowhere to be found; or I don't know where to look. Only if the guest terminates with an error is anything output to the Crossbar log. Here's the configuration:

```
workers:
  - type:       guest
    executable: python3
    arguments:  ['../foo.py']
    options:
      stdout: log
      stderr: log
```

The `stdout` and `stderr` options seem to make no difference whatsoever.

Versions:

- Crossbar.io: 0.10.1
- Autobahn|Python: 0.9.5
- worker: autobahn.asyncio.wamp.ApplicationSession

Answer (score 2):

By default, Python stdout/stderr is buffered so crossbar won't see the logs from the guest when you might think.

You can either set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` or pass the `-u` option to your interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

`crossbar check` validates `stdout: log` and `stderr: log` but Im not sure why it doesn't log the errors.

I normally do it like below but your config looks more clean and handy.

**Setup**

Follow this ([Debugging Crossbar.io app in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476238/debugging-crossbar-io-app-in-intellij/27544912#27544912)). Do similar thing for the IDE you use, however, I recommend to use PyPy for crossbar router instead of CPython.

**Logging**

Follow this ([Logging WAMP worker Trace Back Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999685/logging-wamp-worker-trace-back-error)).
You just gotta enable the Trace Back Error logging feature. You can **`import traceback`** and use **`try except`** or just use create a simple `__init__` function like below:

```python
class MyComponent(ApplicationSession):
   def __init__(self, config = None):
      ApplicationSession.__init__(self, config)
      self.traceback_app = True
```

### Below is a full working example:

**Error log**

[image]

**.crossbar/config.yaml**

```yaml
controller: {}
workers:
- realms:
  - name: realm1
    roles:
    - name: anonymous
      permissions:
      - {call: true, publish: true, register: true, subscribe: true, uri: '*'}
  transports:
  - endpoint: {port: 8080, type: tcp}
    paths:
      /: {directory: .., type: static}
      ws: {type: websocket}
    type: web
  type: router
- arguments: [backend.py]
  executable: ../../../.pyenv/versions/autobahn/bin/python3
  options:
    watch:
      action: restart
      directories: [..]
    workdir: ..
  type: guest
```

**backend.py**

```python
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession
from autobahn import wamp

from asyncio import coroutine
import logging


class MyComponent(ApplicationSession):
    def __init__(self, config = None):
        ApplicationSession.__init__(self, config)
        self.traceback_app = True

    @wamp.register("com.myapp.add2")
    def add2(self, x, y):
        if type(y) is str:
            error = ' Sorry! Python can not add int with something else :('
            logging.critical(error)
            return error

        return x + y

    @coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        res = yield from self.register(self)
        print("{} procedures registered.".format(len(res)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner

    runner = ApplicationRunner(url="ws://localhost:8080/ws", realm="realm1")
    runner.run(MyComponent)
```

**frontend.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>AUTOBAHN_DEBUG = false;</script>
<script src="http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.min.jgz"></script>

<script>
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
        url: "ws://localhost:8080/ws",
        realm: "realm1"
    });

    connection.onopen = function (session, details) {
        // Should work
        session.call("com.myapp.add2", [1, 2]).then(session.log);

        // Expected to log an error
        session.call("com.myapp.add2", [2, "three"]).then(session.log);

        // Expected to log the trace back error
        session.call("com.myapp.add2", ["one", 5]).then(session.log);
    };

    connection.onclose = function (reason, details) {
        console.log("Connection lost: " + reason);
    };

    connection.open();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I basically went to starting the worker myself using a debug run config in PyCharm (I was using that as well anyway), which works like a ... Py... Charm. ^_^;; However, it's still mysterious what the `stdout: log` options is supposed to be used for and why it doesn't work. I'll leave this question open for a little longer, maybe another suggestion will come along...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue of crossbar not outputting anything after the initial startup. Even though there are console.log() in the code. In my case it is with the node.js crossbar router.

The solution was to add "--loglevel=debug" to the start command

```
crossbar start --loglevel=debug
```

Then I started seeing output when console.log() where executed.